# Socrata API missing fields

Tags: socrata

A Socrata API call is missing fields that show up through the Socrata dataset web interface. Here's a sample API call:
https://opendata.fcc.gov/resource/sr6c-syda.json?id=860970

Notice that the returned JSON doesn't include the ticket_created datetime field. But you can see that field via filtering the Ticket Id by 860970 on the web data interface here:

https://opendata.fcc.gov/Consumer-and-Government-Affairs/CGB-Consumer-Complaints-Data/3xyp-aqkj

What explains this discrepancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for missing this question earlier!

Can you double-check your output results? I just tried that same query and I see the `ticket_created` field in the output:

[image]

Comment: Yup, works now. Seems to have been a data load error.